# How to view or render images in Core DB

Tags: user-profile

I have Sitecore User profile pictures saved in Core DB.
In preview mode of a page, the image renders as

http://mysite.org/sitecore/shell/~/media/Profile-Pictures/Demo/author03.ashx?sc_content=core

and is visible.

But the same page when published, renders the image as

http://mysite.org/~/media/Profile-Pictures/Demo/author03.ashx?sc_content=core

and the image is not visible. 
I also updated the permission to the folder in core DB.

[image]

Comment: If you change the image extension in the url from ashx to the image type, does it appears?

Comment: @HishaamNamooya No it doesn't. It seems like access restriction to core db from a published page. But otherwise, aren't images saved as blob

Comment: Why saving images to core db? It mostly used for the sitecore cms. You may either use the sitecore content databases (master, web) or filesystem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it is not working is that it requires Read access. In order to provide the read access, go to the core database and set the security on the item.

For example, I want to access the media item `/sitecore/media library/Experience Profile/Defaults/Channel`. So, from the Core database, I navigate to the image or container and apply a read access to the `extranet/anonymous` or to the specific user.

[image]

**UPDATE**

From the screenshot you provided, you have set the access to the `default\Anonymous` user. You need to set it on the `extranet\Anonymous`.

- Go to the User Manager and select the `extranet\Anonymous`

[image]

- Once selected, click on the Security Editor and set the Read access. An example is shown below:

[image]

Comment: That did not work. I assigned the permissions as said and also uploaded the new pic.

Comment: Can you please share some screenshots of the security editor

Comment: I updated one in question. Please let me know if you need any other

Comment: @Qwerty, I have updated the answer. Please see the Update section

Comment: That worked!!!. Thank you Hishaam. For anyone, who are experiencing the same issue, no need to append "/sitecore/shell". The image src renders differently for preview mode and live mode and it will still work.

Comment: @Qwerty I have updated the answer also on Sitecore Community by adding a link to the question here. Can you please validate it